# Sum of random poisson numbers across data frame

Tags: r

In a simulation I am programming, in each iteration I need to compute the sum of some random poisson numbers for each row in a data frame where the parameters are stored in another column of that row.

Here's a sample of the data (called 'studies' in the code below):

```
    phase Sites enroll_rate rec_months stud_months enrolled m_enroll
51     2     1  2.95920139  2.0000000    5.000000        6        0
52     2    24  0.20784867  2.0000000    5.000000       10        0
53     2     3  0.46501736  3.0000000    6.000000        2        0
54     2     2  1.40480769  3.0000000    6.000000        7        0
55     2     1  1.31299020  5.0000000    7.000000        3        0
64     2    29  0.04373204  0.9712526    1.971253        2        0
```

And here's the code I've been using to achieve this:

```
for (j in 1:nrow(studies)) { 
    studies$m_enroll[j] <- sum(rpois(studies$Sites[j],studies$enroll_rate[j]))
    }
```

This does the job, but given that the data frame is hundreds of rows and I'm doing this simulation tens of thousands of times, it is quite inefficient.

I feel like there's a way to do this using one of the apply functions, but my experience with them is limited. Any ideas?

Comment: No time like the present to learn! :-) .  `m_enroll <- mapply(function (x,y) sum(rpois(x,y)),Sites,enroll_rate)` #not tested, but close enough to get you a running start

Comment: Thanks Carl - worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

```
studies <- studies[rep(1:6,3000),]
system.time(for (j in 1:nrow(studies)){studies$m_enroll[j] <-     
                sum(rpois(studies$Sites[j],studies$enroll_rate[j]))})
   user  system elapsed 
 105.74    0.00  106.30 
system.time(test <- sapply(1:nrow(studies),function(x) 
                    sum(rpois(studies$Sites[x],studies$enroll_rate[x]))))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.36    0.00    0.36
```

Comment: Nice - probably easier to interpret than my pseudocode `mapply`